Salesforce Scheduler - Modifying the flow "Inbound New Guest Appointment"

How do I modify this flow to NOT assign a Service Resource? I just want it to create the Service Appointment and Lead records. The Service Resource ID is saved in the action "Save Appointment" and I've tracked to where it's populated in the "Review Screen", but the input field is required and I can't populate it with {!$GlobalConstant.EmptyString} as it'll throw an error when running the Flow.




How do I modify the Review Service Appointment screen below to remove the fields I've crossed out? At the very least I need the Company removed as this org only deals with Person Accounts and I don't want that field accidentally filled out (it's removed from the Lead layout).


